# Heroku PostgreSQL / NodeJS connection permission denied?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

So I would like to import a local dump to my heroku postgresql db, however, any command I run I just get ...

```
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied (0x0000271D/10013)
        Is the server running on host "ec2-23-23-192-242.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (23.23.192.242) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

This is using the credentials set by the heroku pg add-on, and I have triple checked them to ensure they are correct. Does anyone know why the hell it keeps giving me Permission denied? I can reset the db from the heroku CLI but I can't perform any other action... weird.

Answer (score 0):

you are behind some strict firewall or just isolated from internet, I assume. Look what I get:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -h ec2-23-23-192-242.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xx.xx.xx", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```